# How can i convert bitset into short in c++?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, short, bitset

if i have a `bitset<16> bits(*iter)` and a my short
how i can assign this bist to my short?

```
short myShort = ??bits??
```

It's possible to convert a bitset<16> to short?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You really should use an unsigned short, to avoid language quirks on the high bit.

```
unsigned short myShort = (unsigned short)bits.to_ulong();
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the `to_ulong` method for this, and cast the result (since you know that only the lowest 16 bit will be used):

```
short myShort = static_cast<short>( bits.to_ulong() );
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, `to_ulong` will work. I was feeling some doubt whether the bit order was guaranteed until I looked at the Standard, C++03 §23.3.5/3,

> When converting between an object of class bitset and a value of some integral type, bit position `pos` corresponds to the bit value `1 << pos`. The integral value corresponding to two or more bits is the sum of their bit values.

So, you can cast `to_ulong` to `unsigned short` (or better yet, `uint16_t`) with no worries about overflow or endianness.

Answer (score 0):

use `to_ulong` http://new.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/to_ulong/

Answer (score 0):

```
bitset<16> b;
...   
short myShort = (short)b.to_ulong();
```